# Kotlin multiple variable let, using the previous variables in the next let

Tags: kotlin, option-type, let

I want to be able to have multiple let and the next let is able to use the previous variable *only* if its not null. The reason I want this is because I want only one :? for all the lets. Is this possible?

Example on how I want it to be:

```
fun example() {
  firstVariable?.let a -> &&
  exampleFunction(a, 3)?.let { a, b ->
    // Use a and b freely since they are not null and not optionals
  } ?: run {
    // Runs if either one of the let is failing
  }
}

// a is NOT optional
fun exampleFunction(a: Int, b: Int?): Int? {
  if (b == null) {
    return null
  }

  return a + b
}
```

Stupid example, but its just to show what I need... I want to check if the first variable is null AND to run a function that returns an optional with a non-optional parameter which is the first variable - if either of these fail, I want to run something else.

I know how to do this without let, but I am wondering if it's possible or planned to be able to do this? (It's possible in Swift).

How to do it in Swift:

```
// First check a, then use a in the same expression if its validated
if let a = firstVariable,
   let b = exampleFunction(a) {
  // Use a and b as non-optionals
} else {
  // a or b failed
}
```

Comment: I believe there is no such functionality yet, but you could always create your own extension function if it satisfies you

Comment: I'm not sure how I would write such a function. Could you provide an example? :)

Comment: @Eugene The link does not solve my problem, since the next let cannot use the first result (as I have commented there). As stated: the example functions is stupid, but only to prove my point.

Comment: Does not solve my problem. I want to use the result of the first variable ONLY IF the first variable is not null.

Comment: @Eugene Updated the question to make it more clear what I want to do.

Comment: I know exactly what I want to do, but it's hard to explain. See the Swift code for simple (working) example of the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You propably missunderstood how `let` works. I am going to explain a bit. In short **the desired behaviour is not possible in kotlin** or at least you can not idiomatically emulate it without any drawbacks whatsoever.

I don't know swift but it seems as if the `let` used there is some sort of syntax construct offered by the language itself. It allows you to define a variable with some *local* scope and can be chained (like the short circuiting `&&`).

In Kotlin however `let` is just a normal function.
See the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html). It's basically nothing more than

```
fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R = block(this)
```

It allows to call a function with a normal parameter as a function with a [receiver type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver).

The actual null check is done with the `?.` operator.
It takes an optional/nullable value as left hand side operand and either short circuits returning null or call the function on the right hand side with the non-null left hand side as receiver type. `let` is just one possible function to call here.
The similar `?:` operator takes an optional/nullable LHS operand and returns this value if it is not null or it evaluates the expression on the RHS.

One way to get those variables defined is by nesting `let`s:

```
firstVariable?.let{a -> exampleFunction(a, 3)?.let{b -> a + b}} ?: run{}
```

where `a + b` is just an example of using both values. This however becomes unhandy if it's longer than one line. If you still want to define local variables you can create a block with `run` and use jump statements on the right side of `?:`

```
run {
    val a = firstValue ?: return@run null
    val b = exampleFunction(a, 3) ?: return@run null
    return@run a + b
} ?: run{}
```

While the above code looks really ugly with all those `return@run null` repititions there might be ways to reduce the amount of repeating code e.g. by using a anonymous function (to get rid of the `@run` part) or return `Unit` and safe the last value with some side-effect operation. (to get rid of the `null` and the last return statement)

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. I understood that this was not possible with let itself, I was wondering if it was possible in some other way. Your way with run's solves the problem. (Yes, it's ugly, but its exactly the functionality I was looking for!) Maybe a nicer way of doing this will be a feature for the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could benefit on Kotlin and write sot of extension function for your case. `vararg` as we dont know how many variables we want to pass, then check if all of them are not null and if so, return all of them. If any of the vars will be null, then nothing happens.

```
fun <T: Any> multipleLetCheck(vararg variables: T?, block: (List<T>) -> Unit): Unit? {
    return if (variables.all { variable -> variable != null }) {
        block(variables.filterNotNull())
    } else {
        null
    }
}

// usage
multipleLetCheck(firstVariable, 3){ (firstVariable, secondVariable) ->
    // work with firstVariable and secondVariable
} ?: run {

}
```

Comment: This is fine, but it does not solve my problem: I want to run a function with the first variable ONLY if its not null.

Comment: I also want the return values of the let's to be able to have different types

Comment: `block(variables.filterNotNull())` filternotnull not required here because of your .all{}

Comment: all{} returns Array not list

Comment: I am not sure if I get you @Otziii, but see the edit. Now if any of the variables is null then `run{}` will execute. This is what you seek for ?

Comment: @P.Juni It's a bit hard to explain, but I basically need to run a let on the first variable and in the same scope - run another let using the result of the first let ONLY if the result is no null. Please try to read the original question and comments in the code to try to understad what I want to do.

Comment: In Swift you can do this by: if let aNotNull = a, let b = functionThatReturnsOptional(aNotNull) { //use a and b }

Comment: Could be something like && operator between lets or something.

Comment: I believe my example does this. But if you are interested only in checking the First one, maybe change `all{}` to `variables.first() != null`?

Comment: I get error when I try because when I try to use the first parameter in the function call which is the second parameter - it is not validated yet i.e -> still an optional which I cannot send in to the function.

Comment: @P.Juni Updated the question. Please see if you understand the need. :)